# How to design "anonymous" functionality in the backend - good design patterns

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, redis, backend

When developing the notification center, we want to push newly generated notifications to the user. <sub><sub>(using WebSocket, but that is unrelated to the question.)</sub></sub> However, the notifications is generated very fast, so we want to use the *throttle* method (a term [in Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle), or see [this visualization](http://demo.nimius.net/debounce_throttle/)). We will throttle the "notification generated" event.

A visualization: X-axis is time. The first blue row is the generated notifications, not necessarily same time interval of course. The red row is the throttled events. (ignore green)

[image]

The problem is how to implement this. We have a naive solution as follows:

1. Whenever a notification is generated, enqueue a "delayed task" into Kafka with delay=throttleTime.
2. When Kafka deliver a delayed message to us, check the `lastActionTimestamp` in Redis. If `currentTimestamp - lastActionTimestamp < throttleTime`, it means that this message should be throw away. Otherwise, do action, and update the `lastActionTimestamp` in Redis to be the current time.

I think it is a little bit complicated. So is there any better or simpler methods? Or are there any libraries? Thanks!

---

**Disclaimer**: It is *not* the often-seen "throttling" - *not* wanting to rate-limit some user actions or microservice calls.

Comment: I think that ultimately, if you want to "coalesce" the alerts and only pick the last one over a time window, there's no escape to have a last value cache somewhere keeping the state for the current time window/topic. If your problem domain allows it, i would keep that state as close as possible (i.e. local, in memory) to the producer, and avoid send the message in the first place. This might not be feasible if the same alerts are sent by multiple producers.

Comment: @white-surf-style-five Yes those alerts may be sent by any machine in the cluster so I have to use some centralized storage. Anyway thanks all the same!

Comment: I'm not expert with kafka (never used it myself), but maybe you can write a stream processing application with Kafka streams (it's open source), performing aggregations over a time window (https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/concepts.html#streams-concepts-windowing) with a 'pick last one' aggregation strategy.

Comment: @white-surf-style-five Thanks! I will have a look